# INSERT multiple ROWS for same ID Syntax Error

Tags: php, sql

I want to insert a lot of rows into my sql database but it gives me an error. i have 3 fields (object_id, key, value) and for every object from a different table i want to store additional values in longtext format and no auto increment sql server error says i use the wrong syntax. i tried it with '', `` and also without everything but it wont work what i am doing wrong?

```
  $ff = $db->last_inserted_id();

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO object_meta (`object_id`, `key`, `value`)
      VALUES ($ff, 'title', '$title'),
      VALUES ($ff, 'nice_url', '$nice_url'),
      VALUES ($ff, 'menu_title', '$menutitle'),
      VALUES ($ff, 'content', '$text'),
      VALUES ($ff, 'description', '$description'),
      VALUES ($ff, 'keywords', '$keywords'),
      VALUES ($ff, 'status', '$status'),
      VALUES ($ff, 'date', '$date')";

    $db->query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: "but it gives me an error" --- and its exact text is a secret?

Comment: i use the wrong syntax, as i said..

Comment: in the error message mysql points you to the exact issue you've made. "Wrong syntax" is not what mysql would tell you.

Comment: @user3421973 - I find it very unlikely that the `exact` error message was `i use the wrong syntax`

Comment: me too, but there was not much more.. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '11, 'title', 'hgfhf'), (11, 'nice_url', 'kjhg'), (11, 'menu_title', ' at line 2

Comment: Is object_id a primary key? Could you be inserting the same key every time for a field that must be unique?

Comment: Maybe try adding `'$ff'` for every `$ff`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to use `VALUES` once, even if you are inserting multiple rows.

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO object_meta (`object_id`, `key`, `value`)
  VALUES ($ff, 'title', '$title'),
         ($ff, 'nice_url', '$nice_url'),
         ($ff, 'menu_title', '$menutitle'),
         ($ff, 'content', '$text'),
         ($ff, 'description', '$description'),
         ($ff, 'keywords', '$keywords'),
         ($ff, 'status', '$status'),
         ($ff, 'date', '$date')";
```

I have tested this with PHP 5.3 and PDO running on Mac, connecting to a MySQL 5.6 instance running on Linux. I confirm this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO 
    object_meta (`object_id`, `key`, `value`)
VALUES 
($ff, 'title', '$title'),
($ff, 'nice_url', '$nice_url'),
...
```

You can't repeat VALUES

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
  $ff = $db->last_inserted_id();

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO object_meta (`object_id`, `key`, `value`)
      VALUES ('$ff', 'title', '$title'),
      VALUES ('$ff', 'nice_url', '$nice_url'),
      VALUES ('$ff', 'menu_title', '$menutitle'),
      VALUES ('$ff', 'content', '$text'),
      VALUES ('$ff', 'description', '$description'),
      VALUES ('$ff', 'keywords', '$keywords'),
      VALUES ('$ff', 'status', '$status'),
      VALUES ('$ff', 'date', '$date')";

    $db->query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

(added '' to $ff)